# Are Python sets mutable?

Tags: python, set

Are sets in Python mutable?

---

In other words, if I do this:

```
x = set([1, 2, 3])
y = x

y |= set([4, 5, 6])
```

Are `x` and `y` still pointing to the same object, or was a new set created and assigned to `y`?

Comment: It is easier to detect than to ask about... `print x is y` would be applicable as well here.

Comment: Yes, They would point to the same object instance

Comment: Erm... Are all these down votes because the question is about something that is easy to check? Because I don't currently have access to a Python interpreter, and I couldn't find the answer online, so that's a stupid reason to down vote a question.

Comment: @glglgl: How is that relevant to whether or not its a valid question? Not everyone has quick access to a Python interpreter.

Comment: @Codemonkey I think it's reasonable to expect people who ask programming questions to have access to the language in which they're trying to program.

Comment: If you have access to the internet, how do you not have access to an interpreter? There are _numerous_ in-browser interpreters, as a quick Google search will show you.

Comment: Also, you should be able to _immediately_ see that sets are mutable by looking at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: My +1 to the question. The wording may not be the same what is the author thinking about. (Would the question "Are sets in Python *really* mutable?" be more acceptable?). And also, almost everything can be found in the doc. This way, any question that can be explained via studying the doc would not be legitimate. I do not think there are "stupid questions". Everyone is at a different level. Some beginners may be 70 years old, some experts can be 12. There are different ways of getting knowledge.

Comment: @glglgl a simple test can't tell you if they're required to be the same object, only that they are in this particular implementation of Python. Everything could change with the next upgrade if you're not careful. I think that makes this a legitimate question.

Comment: @Hubro, yes the x and y pointing to same object. you can check with the id(x) == id(y), which will return True

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
>>>> x = set([1, 2, 3])
>>>> y = x
>>>> 
>>>> y |= set([4, 5, 6])

>>>> print x
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>>> print y
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

- Sets are unordered.
- Set elements are unique. Duplicate elements are not allowed.
- A set itself may be modified, but the elements contained in the set must be of an immutable type.

```
set1 = {1,2,3}

set2 = {1,2,[1,2]}  --> unhashable type: 'list'
# Set elements should be immutable.
```

Conclusion: sets are mutable.

Comment: Note there exists a built-in immutable set class: [`frozenset`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset).

Comment: @celestialroad @Tom, it's `update`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: See my answer, sets can contain mutable types.

Answer (score 23):

Your two questions are different.

> Are Python sets mutable?

Yes: "mutable" means that you can change the object. For example, integers are not mutable: you cannot change the number `1` to mean anything else. You can, however, add elements to a set, which mutates it.

> Does `y = x; y |= {1,2,3}` change `x`?

Yes. The code `y = x` means "bind the name `y` to mean the same object that the name `x` currently represents". The code `y |= {1,2,3}` calls the magic method `y.__ior__({1,2,3})` under the hood, which mutates the object represented by the name `y`. Since this is the same object as is represented by `x`, you should expect the set to change.

---

You can check whether two names point to precisely the same object using the `is` operator: `x is y` just if the objects represented by the names `x` and `y` are the same object.

If you want to copy an object, the usual syntax is `y = x.copy()` or `y = set(x)`. This is only a *shallow* copy, however: although it copies the set object, the *members* of said object are not copied. If you want a deepcopy, use `copy.deepcopy(x)`.

Comment: I don't see how the two questions are different. If sets were not mutable, `y` would be pointing to a different object than `x`, just like with string concatenation.

Comment: @Codemonkey False: `x = "hello"; y = x; y is x` is `True`. The syntax `y = x` _always_ makes y and x point to the same object. Can you explain what you mean by "like with string concatenation"?

Comment: @katrielalex But if you then do concatenation, `"y += " world"`, `y` points to a different object than `x`, whereas with a mutable object it doesn't, which is what he's doing in the question.

Comment: @agf right, that's a side-effect of mutable objects in the stdlib having `__i<foo>__` methods. There's no guarantee that a mutable object will have these, nor that an immutable won't. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: @katrielalex: Nit-picking - it's pretty obvious what I meant.

Comment: My +1 to the answer. (And I do not understand why it was downvoted. Anyone who downvotes should be sure he understands what he downvotes.) @Codemonkey: Any assignment in Python means sharing of the same object. If the object is mutable, you change its value, but you do not change sharing. You can never mutate immutable objects. The `y += " world"` for strings creates a new object and the resulting object is assigned to the `y` variable. In other words, the `y` is reassigned (reused) to point to something different than the original object (`x`).

Comment: @katrielalex [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ior__) say: "These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self)." So a mutable object should always mutate itself and return `self`. An immutable object should generate the result as a new object and return it. It is indeed not a guarantee nor a requirement, but a strong recommendation.

Comment: @pepr: I am completely aware of that. I don't know what I said that gave you the impression that I didn't know that.

Comment: @Codemonkey: Yes, ok. Sorry. The question, answers, and myself are a bit confused :) I hope it did not hurt you.

Comment: @pepr: Of course not :) It's very nice of you to elaborately explain a topic to somebody who seems confused - keep it up.

Comment: I'm curious, what would the purpose of a deepcopy of a set be? A set must contain hashable (and afaik, immutable) objects, so why would a deepcopy be more advantageous here?

Comment: @Kupiakos you're basically right, but hashable doesn't technically imply immutable (`class Foo: def __hash__(self): return 0`).

Comment: @katrielalex Ah yes, that clears things up. I'm curious why one would make a mutable and hashable object, but Python is all about programmer responsibility and freedom for whatever weird stuff you want. Kinda cool.

Comment: I can't comprehend, why are sets mutable, when I see the following example:

    >>> s = set((1,2,3))
    >>> s
    {1, 2, 3}
    >>> s[2] = 4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#74>", line 1, in <module>
        s[2] = 4
    TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment
    >>> 

Could you please explain it to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't assign to `s[2]` because sets aren't ordered. You can do `s.add(4)` to add 4 to the set, though.

Answer (score 14):

Python sets are classified into two types. Mutable and immutable. A set created with 'set' is mutable while the one created with 'frozenset' is immutable.

```
>>> s = set(list('hello'))
>>> type(s)
<class 'set'>
```

The following methods are for mutable sets.

s.add(item) -- Adds item to s. Has no effect if `list`is already in s.

s.clear() -- Removes all items from s.

s.difference_update(t) -- Removes all the items from s that are also in t.

s.discard(item) -- Removes item from s. If item is not a member of s, nothing happens.

All these operations modify the set s in place. The parameter t can be any object that supports iteration.

Answer (score 3):

After changing the set, even their object references match. I don't know why that textbook says sets are immutable.

```
    >>> s1 ={1,2,3}
    >>> id(s1)
    140061513171016
    >>> s1|={5,6,7}
    >>> s1
    {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}
    >>> id(s1)
    140061513171016
```

Comment: which textbook was this ?

Comment: Learning python by Mark Lutz (5th Edition). Maybe the textbook was referring to some python version which was released at that point of time.

Comment: If you really want immutable sets, there is something called "frozenset" in python where sets have immutability.

Comment: Is the textbook reference referrring to [pawandeep singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193438/are-python-sets-mutable/47966508#47966508)? That contains a screenshot from a textbook.

Answer (score 2):

```
print x,y
```

and you see they both point to the same set:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 2):

Sets are muttable

```
s = {2,3,4,5,6}
type(s)
<class 'set'>
s.add(9)
s
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9}
```

We are able to change elements of set

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Python sets are mutable because we can add, delete elements into set, but sets can't contain mutable items into itself. Like the below code will give an error:

```
s = set([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

So sets are mutable but can't contain mutable items, because set internally uses hashtable to store its elements so for that set elements need to be hashable.
But mutable elements like list are not hashable.

Note:
**Mutable** elements are not hashable
**Immutable** elements are hashable

Just like key of a dictionary can't be a list.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are mutable, you can add to them. The items they contain CAN BE MUTABLE THEY MUST BE HASHABLE. I didn't see any correct answers in this post so here is the code

```
class MyClass:
"""
    This class is hashable, however, the hashes are
    unique per instance not the data so a set will
    have no way to determine equality
"""
def __init__(self):
    self.my_attr = "no-unique-hash"
def __repr__(self):
    return self.my_attr

class MyHashableClass:
    """
        This object implements __hash__ and __eq__ and will
    produce the same hash if the data is the same. 
    That way a set can remove equal objects.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attr = "unique-hash"
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return hash(self) == hash(other)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.my_attr

myclass_instance1 = MyClass()
myclass_instance2 = MyClass()

my_hashable_instance1 = MyHashableClass()
my_hashable_instance2 = MyHashableClass()

my_set = {
    myclass_instance1,
    myclass_instance2,
    my_hashable_instance1,
    my_hashable_instance2, # will be removed, not unique
} # sets can contain mutuable types
# The only objects set can not contain are objects
# with the __hash__=None, such as List, Dict, and Sets

print(my_set)
# prints {unique-hash, no-unique-hash, no-unique-hash }

my_hashable_instance1.my_attr = "new-hash"  # mutating the object

# now that the hashes between the objects are differrent
# instance2 can be added
my_set.add(my_hashable_instance2) 

print(my_set)
# {new-hash, no-unique-hash, no-unique-hash, unique-hash}
```

Comment: Just to clarify a type being hashable does not mean it is immutable

Answer (score -3):

I don't think Python sets are mutable as mentioned clearly in book "**Learning Python 5th Edition by Mark Lutz - O'Reilly Publications**"

[image]

Comment: The elements of the set are immutable, the set itself is mutable.